# Sugest me, Planing to create a REST based API using MVP under SharePoint 2010

Tags: mvc

for almost a year now i was working with few open source technologies, and so habituated to it... this pushed me to create a REST based architecture for SharePoint 2010 using ASP.Net MVC 2/3...

Since it has lot many advantages to it

- First off all; Get rid off the so called service calls {WCF}, nastier isn't so
- We can pull down the all the objects complete to client side, design a beautiful client-side applications {or} we can make use of some amazing client-side framework to work with e.g. KnockOutJS, BackboneJS.
- Most importantly, it's UI agonistic

  Share if you have anything similar to it...

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 already exposes most of its content through its REST interface, implementation the ODATA protocol.

Prior to develop something custom from scratch, I would seriously look into what's available, even in the free foundation edition. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587.aspx

I've built heavy client side applications nearly solely relying on the ootb REST interface. Extremely powerful once on deep dive into it.

Comment: Thanks very much for response, last week i had come up some beautifull .net REST framework for sharepoint, now i'm building one using [StackService](http://www.servicestack.net/)...

Comment: You need ORM from [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src)